# Android 2.1 using 4.4 sdk - How to send data using HTTP POST request?

Tags: android

This is my UI layout:
[image]

I want to send some msg by using HTTP POST request.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText editmsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMessage);
        EditText editmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMail);
        Button btnsubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnsubmit.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = isw.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                data = isw.read();
                System.out.print(current);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I came to know that httpclient is not supported to higher sdk version. So please, help me how to write code for http request post to send some msg and email with given url.

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: i just want to know ......how to write code ...like i want to send some msg and email to the given url by clicking the send button....using http post request ....so plz help me

Comment: You better read some pages of this site with tag android. Set the page at 50 items. Every day you can read here how to post. If you google a bit you will find code to send an email. Or an sms.

Comment: i am trying to fix since 2 day ....am searching everywhere ...but i am not understanding.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void makePostRequest() {


    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            // replace with your url
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("www.example.com"); 


    //Post Data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "test_user"));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "123456789"));


    //Encoding POST data
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // log exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //making POST request.
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        // write response to log
        Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // Log exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Found here: http://hayageek.com/android-http-post-get/

It's pretty well self documented, but if you need further help, feel free to ask ;)

Comment: I have tried but HTTPCLIENT is deprecated.so i using urlconnection.

Comment: Ok, then I strongly suggest you to take a look at Volley: http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html. It's an HTTP library designed to make really simple sending data for Android.